# Jenkins getting FATAL: Could not initialize class com.microsoft.tfs.core.config.persistence.DefaultPersistenceStoreProvider

Tags: java, jenkins, tfs

I was on Jenkins 2.22 and wanted to upgrade to 2.153.  I do have snapshots before I upgrade.   I am using war files.  Java version 1.8, I am on Solaris 11.3.

After I upgraded, it required me to upgrade to tfs 5.142 then I started to get following error.  The frustrating thing was now even I rolled back snapshots, to Jenkins version 2.22, TFS 5.2.1, I am getting the same errors.  It seems all of sudden nothing seems to be working.

[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building on master in workspace /apps/jenkins2/workspace/buildx
FATAL: Could not initialize class com.microsoft.tfs.core.config.persistence.DefaultPersistenceStoreProvider
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.microsoft.tfs.core.config.persistence.DefaultPersistenceStoreProvider
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Server.(Server.java:114)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Server.create(Server.java:72)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.TeamFoundationServerScm.createServer(TeamFoundationServerScm.java:441)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.TeamFoundationServerScm.checkout(TeamFoundationServerScm.java:285)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1278)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:604)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1720)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)

what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

There's a [closed issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/JENKINS-34602) in jenkins, solution is to deleting the user profile

> Deleting the slave's user profile on the slave (and thus wiping out any old 'rubbish') solved the issue. Hinted from https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/

Comment: I am getting this error on Jenkins master, in early stage of the build process.